Draw mode is unusable
This question has been posed but I have not seen the resolution.  Basically I am trying to use grease pencil in draw mode, but I get a small amount of a line then it stops.  I cannot draw a continuous line.  This happens with both mouse and Wacom tablet, but in other draw programs all is fine.  So I really am stuck with any animation at this point.  I am running Windows 11 with i7 core@1.8GHz with 16Gbytes ram.  Blender is version 4.1.  Full disclosure, I am a newbie so this could easily be pilot error!

Sadly we can't debug your issue with as little informations. Consider adding pictures. If it's a bug, this isn't the right place for that. https://developer.blender.org/docs/handbook/bug_reports/making_good_bug_reports/

Consider checking your brush settings and seeing which brush is being used. There are several brushes in Blender that draw a straight line as a series of dots. (not sure if I understood the question correctly but this is what it sounds like to me)
